# Why am I getting a bad host response after this TCP connection to stackoverflow using Java?

Tags: java, sockets, http, web, tcp

This is my code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("198.252.206.16",80);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes("GET http://stackoverflow.com:80 HTTP/1.1\n\nHost: http://stackoverflow.com\n");
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int x;
        while((x = inputStreamReader.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) x);
        }
    }
}
```

And the response I am getting is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 18:47:26 GMT
Content-Length: 334

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the `Host` header as part of the body of your GET request.

```
outToServer.writeBytes("GET http://stackoverflow.com:80 HTTP/1.1\n\nHost: http://stackoverflow.com\n");
//                                                               ^ notice two new lines
```

So your GET is like

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com:80 HTTP/1.1  // << request method and headers

Host: http://stackoverflow.com  // << request body
```

Instead, only put one new line there, and two at the end

```
outToServer.writeBytes("GET http://stackoverflow.com:80 HTTP/1.1\nHost: http://stackoverflow.com\n\n");
```

It will be correct like

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com:80 HTTP/1.1  // << request method and headers
Host: http://stackoverflow.com
```